# Getting per-thread CPU usage (task-clock) using 'perf'

Tags: linux, perf

all

I'm running multi-threaded application and want to measure per-thread CPU usage.
For instance, I want to see

> thread-0 17696.260293 task-clock
>
> thread-1 244112.601727 task-clock
>
> ...

Can anyone let me know how to get this kind of information using 'perf' or some other performance monitoring tool?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably `perf record --event=task-clock ...`

Comment: .. or `--per-thread` option of `perf record`?

Comment: I'm also looking for something like that but, unfortunately perf doesn't breakdown the cycles on [per-thread basis](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_and_inheritance)